# Como posso fazer update no MySQL em uma coluna inteira se outra estiver fazia?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Galera alguém inteligente pode me ajudar com isso?

Tenho uma tabela no MySQL de nome "Sellers" E queria que todas as linhas de uma coluna "seller_image_s3" recebesse um update de valor "1" se a coluna "seller_image" estiver preenchida. Mas se caso essa coluna "seller_image" estiver vazia, a coluna "seller_image_s3" receba um UPDADE de valor "0".

Alguém poderia criar uma consulta pra que eu possa executar?
Ficaria muuuuuito grato.

Comment: tem q testar se a sintaxe está correta para o mysql...`update sellers set seller_image_s3 = (case when seller_image is null then 0 else 1 end);`

Comment: Você poderia me mostrar como ficaria a consulta? Eu quero fazer a alteração direito pelo php myadmin

Comment: se vc quer alterar é update, e é o comando que escrevi acima...